# JSON-LD Schema Clashing with Facebook Pixel

Tags: schema, json-ld

I have recently been creating my own JSON-LD schema for my Wordpress site.

I have run the schema through Googles Structured data testing tool and all is well.

However, once I insert it to the page I am getting an error "fbevents.js:23 [Facebook Pixel] - Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found: '{" - then the entire schema is shown in the console. This is happening on every page I have Facebook Pixel running on.

I have never had the issue before with schema plugins etc so I am assuming its something I am doing - does anyone have any ideas?

URL: https://www.thetravellinghousesitters.com/how-to-become-a-house-sitter/

If anyone needs anymore information let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right at the end of your How-to you have an extra comma:

"totalTime": "P2D"
},

I suspect the SDTT can deal with that syntax error, but Facebook can't.

Comment: That actually worked! 

Thank you Tony I really appreciate you taking a look at this. This is something that has been doing my head in for a very long time now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  For some reason, I had a semicolon at the end of my JSON Code.

Removed and it all works fine now.

```
                    "bestRating": 5,
                    "ratingValue": 5
                }
            }
    }]
};   // This semicolon in the last line was the culprit
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I included comments in my Schema.  The Google Validator would say it's all right, but the Facebook Pixel would clash with ANY commenting.